# Why mode RewriteRule does not work properly?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I make rewrite mode in htaccess but it does not work, why? I want to make nice url `www.domain.com/contact` from ugly `www.domain.com/index.php?route=information/contact`

```
RewriteRule ^contact$ index.php?route=information/contact[L]
```

here is my current .htaccess

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap/sitemap-index.xml [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f                                                   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Put a space before the `[L]`.

Comment: yes, I have a space RewriteRule ^contact$ index.php?route=information/contact [L]

Comment: what exactly isn't working?

Comment: mode rewrite does not working, nothing happens

Comment: Is the mod-rewrite enabled? What happens when you type the new url in your browser?

Comment: mode-rewrite is enable, when I type new url it will be 404 page not found. But goal is not to type new url but change automatically from ugly to nice

Comment: Please include your entire `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Does have any impact what else is in the .htaccess?

Comment: any idea how to fix it?